# PowerBI web service date parameter

Tags: .net, web-services, date, powerbi

I am having an issue passing date parameters to a pentaho web service, but when passing parameter as date it says:

Below is the call that is being made to the web service on my local machine.
Parameter name is **date_start**

**Web.Contents("http://localhost:8081/kettle/executeTrans/?trans=E:\pentaho\dashboard.ktr&date_start="&date_start)**

We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Date. I can not use data type of the parameter as text as i have used slicer on the dashboard and that parameter is passed as the starting date to it, and it only accepts the date data type param.

what should i do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so far i have managed to solve the issue by type casting the **date** to **text** as i pass it to the web service.

I used the function **`Date.ToText(filter_date_to, "yyyy-MM-dd")`**,

i could have used **`Text.From(filter_date_to)`** function as well, but i needed to reformat the date before typecasting, so this worked like a charm.

Hope this helps anyone else with the same requirement/issue.